# Python xml - how to loop through <tbody> to get data

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have added an snippet of the html i wish to scrape.

I would like to go through each row (tbody) and scrape the relevant data using xml.

the xss for each row can be found by the following:

```
//*[@id="re_"]/table/tbody
```

but im unsure how to set it up in python to loop through each tbody? there is not set number for the tbody rows so could range from any number.
eg.

```
 for each tbody:   
      ...get data
```

below is the HTML page

http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=651402&r_date=2016-06-07&popup=yes#results_top_tabs=re_&results_bottom_tabs=ANALYSIS

Comment: Can you add the racingpost link you are scraping from?

Comment: Sorry i have added the actual page itself

Comment: What lib are you currently using?

Comment: Im using lxml  to do it

Comment: Good, I added a working lxml example. You don't really care about the div as the tbody tags are in the table so extracting from that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *lxml*, you can pull the table directly using the class name and extract all the tbody tags with the xpath `//table[@class="grid resultRaceGrid"]/tbody`

```
from lxml import html

x = html.parse("http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=651402&r_date=2016-06-07&popup=yes#results_top_tabs=re_&results_bottom_tabs=ANALYSIS")

tbodys= x.xpath('//table[@class="grid resultRaceGrid"]/tbody')
# iterate over the list of tbody tags
for tbody in tbodys:
    # get all the rows from the tbody
    for row in tbody.xpath("./tr"):
        # extract the tds and do whatever you want.
        tds = row.xpath("./td")
        print(tds)
```

Obviously you can be more specific, the td tags have class names which you can use to extract  and some tr tags also have classes.

Comment: why when running it do i get loads of [<Element td at 0x4b8a908>]

Comment: What would you expect to get? The code pulls all the td tags from each row

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. Like I said in the answer, you can choose to only pull or specific td etc.. using their class name if you only want certain ones.

Comment: what if i had full path so say //*[@id="re_"]/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[4]/span/b/a/text()

Comment: You could do that  but using a class or attribute is a lot more reliable.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking you'd be interested in [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

With your data, if you wanted to print all comment texts, it would be as simple as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for tbody in soup.find_all('tbody'):
    print tbody.find('.commentText').get_text()
```

You can do much more fancy stuff. You can [read more here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: if the reason for the downvote is  because of tbody, then that's not part of the question. How that html was generated is irrelevant. What to do with it - is.